# How to get separate total amount of records for given list of ids in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working with a question answer forum.

What I am trying to do this is pretty straightforward.

In questions list page, I want to show total number of answers a question have.

I know how to get all answers amount from a question record -

```
answer_records = Answer.objects.filter(question = question_record).count()
```

But, I want a single query which generates separate answer records amount for all given question records. So far I have tried -

```
answer_records = Answer.objects.filter(question__in = question_records).count()
```

It only generates single count of all question records.

Here is my model -

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    views = models.BigIntegerField(default = 0)
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True)
    answer_text = models.TextField(default = '')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

How can I do that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here is a list comprehensions:

`[Answer.objects.filter(question = question_record).count() for question_record in Question.ojects.all()]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to do `GROUP BY` on `questions` and return the `COUNT` of answers for each `question`. For achieving this, you may use `.annotate()` as:

```
Answer.objects.filter(question__in= question_records) \
    .values('question') \
    .annotate(question_count= COUNT('question'))
```

Also take a look at [Django's Document on *"Generating aggregates for each item in a QuerySet"*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset). You will find it useful.

---

`values()` : specifies which columns are going to be used to "group by"

Django docs:

> "When a values() clause is used to constrain the columns that are
>   returned in the result set, the method for evaluating annotations is
>   slightly different. Instead of returning an annotated result for each
>   result in the original QuerySet, the original results are grouped
>   according to the unique combinations of the fields specified in the
>   values() clause"

`annotate()` : specifies an operation over the grouped values

Django docs:

> The second way to generate summary values is to generate an independent summary for each object in a QuerySet. For example, if you
>   are retrieving a list of books, you may want to know how many authors
>   contributed to each book. Each Book has a many-to-many relationship
>   with the Author; we want to summarize this relationship for each book
>   in the QuerySet.
>
> Per-object summaries can be generated using the annotate() clause.
>   When an annotate() clause is specified, each object in the QuerySet
>   will be annotated with the specified values.

Comment: It doesn't give question wise result. Every time it sums up all records in new set.

Comment: Try replacing `question` with `question_id` in `values()` and `.annotate()`. It's been a long time since iI used Django. Also replace `SUM` with `COUNT`

Comment: I think you should rewrite it like `.annotate(question_count=Count('question')).values('id', 'question_count')`. That way you will get the results as dictionaries: {'id': smth, 'question_count': smth2}.